# What memory/data structure should I use to divide the memory into blocks/chunks and its implementation?

Tags: c++, data-structures, garbage-collection, chunks

**(THE ALLOCATED DATA CAN BE OF ANY TYPE - int, char, etc..)**

I am given a sheet size of 1024 bytes and a maximum of 5 sheets. I need to make some sort of dynamically allocated structure (or structures) that will keep all of the data in one place and divide it into blocks. So I basically need to allocate 1024 bytes (or maybe all of the space I have, 1024x5 bytes) in a structure and use the given memory in blocks differently. And if the sheet runs out of memory I need to allocate a new one.

So my question is: **What would be the best structure in c++ for this job?** I was thinking either a vector of char* or void* or maybe a classic c array of char* or void*, but not quite too sure. If it is an array I was wondering maybe I make an array[5] and allocate just the first element and the first element would be a pointer to 1024 bytes of memory?

Here are the functions that will be done with the structure (its a simple implementation of a garbage collector):

1.Allocate block of memory of a given size and return a pointer to that memory

2.Free a block of memory given a "void *region" attribute

3.Increase size of block with given "void *region" and size to increase to

4.Decrease size of block with given "void *region" and size to decrease to

5. Write information for the allocated blocks of memory in a file

Note: All of the functions are in a class garbage collector and all of them are static of type void (except for the first one, which is of type void*, because it returns a pointer to the newly allocated block)

Note 2: The pages aren't allocated one after another in the machine's memory, so they have different adresses, they're only allocated when they're needed (when space is running out)

Comment: Keep it simple. `using page = uint8_t[1024]; page pages[5] = { allocate_page(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't specify but the memory can be of any type.

Comment: You could have a `struct Sheet { uint8_t data[1024]{}; };` and then a `struct Sheets { std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sheet>> data{}; }`. Encapsulating your code in `Sheets` will allow you to manage things like a max capacity of `5`.

Comment: What does "the memory can be of any type" mean? Are you talking about the backing memory (your pages) or the memory managed by your allocator ?

Comment: The memory that will be used after being allocated. So the data contained in each of the pages can be of any type. Meaning that I dynamically allocate one page and then that memory will be used like in a garbage collector - I could have for example int a = gc.allocate(4) or char b = gc.allocate(1) or a whole array

Comment: That is irrelevant for a memory allocator. It just needs to hand back a different flavor of pointer (see `reinterpret_cast` or C-style casts) OR put that burden on the user (who will have to the cast themself)

Comment: But why would it be irrelevant? Because the memory that is being allocated will be used for storing different variables and arrays and etc.

Comment: A memory allocator thinks in terms of blocks of a given size with a given alignment. Casting the returned block to the required type is trivial: `template <class T> T* allocate(int count = 1) { return (T*)raw_allocate(count * sizeof T); }` Call as `allocate<int>(42)` to get an `int*` to an array of 42 `int`s. Note that the required memory also needs to be aligned to `std::alignment_of_v<T>`; see `std::align` for that. But all of that comes *after* you implement the (de)allocation of blocks, so *get that working first*

Comment: Well, if you want to create a poor-man's malloc, why not look at what a real one does and then scale down the implementation to your needs? https://azeria-labs.com/heap-exploitation-part-1-understanding-the-glibc-heap-implementation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start out with something like this :

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
struct heap_t
{
public:

    // todo add your memory managment 
    // using templates like 

    template<typename type_t>
    type_t* allocate()
    {
        // use sizeof(type_t) etc...
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<typename type_t>
    void free(type_t* ptr)
    {
        // more logic here.
    }

private:
    std::array<char, N> m_memory{0}; // initialize all memory to 0
};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t heap_size{ 256ul };

    // to avoid allocating heap on the stack use make_unique
    auto heap = std::make_unique<heap_t<heap_size>>();
    
    auto value_ptr = heap->allocate<int>();
    
    return 0;
}
```